# Image Drag Drop and Upload in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

*I'm using node.js, express, mongoose.*

I have a form that allows a user to either
1. Click "Upload Image" and upload an image
2. Drag an image from their computer into the dropbox to upload the image

1. works as expected. I'm having trouble with 2. Basically, I'm able to drop the image into the dropzone, but **when the form is submitted, the image is never actually uploaded**. I read a lot, but can't seem to find a solution.

*I'm aware of dropzone.js, but decided not to use it just to learn how to do this on my own.*

This is how my dropbox looks like (just so that you understand the code):
[image]

Basically when a user clicks upload or drags an image into the dropbox, it appears in the preview. This works.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**new.ejs**

```
<input name="image" type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

   <div id="imageBorder" >
        <div id="imageContainer">

             <div id="dropbox">
                   <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p> Drop image here or click to upload</p>
             </div>

             <div id="preview" class="hidden">
             </div>

             <button id="fileSelect" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload Image</button>
            <button id="fileRemove" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Remove Image</button>

</div>
```

**eventform.js**

```
function eventImageSetup() {

var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("image"),
    fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileRemove = document.getElementById("fileRemove");

$(dropbox).height($('#imageBorder').height());

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (fileElem) {
      fileElem.click();
      e.preventDefault(); // to prevent submit
    }
}, false);

fileRemove.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
    if(!$('#preview').hasClass('hidden')) { // If there is an image uploaded
        $('#preview').empty(); 
        $('#dropbox').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#preview').addClass('hidden');
        $('#fileSelect').text('Upload Image');
        resetFileInputField();
    }
    removeError($('#imageError'), $('#image'));
});

dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

} // end of eventImageSetup


function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  handleFiles(files);
}

  function handleFiles(files) { 


    var file = files[0];

    console.log("This is the file: ", file);

    var imageType = /^image\//;
    if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
      // a bunch of code to deal with this...
      return;
   } else if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
      // a bunch of code to deal with this..
     return; 
 } else {

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.onload = function() {
            adjustImageSize(img);
      };
      $('#dropbox').addClass('hidden');
      $('#preview').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#preview').empty();
      $('#preview').append(img);
      $('#fileSelect').text('Replace Image');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function(event) {
          img.src = event.target.result;
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the problem is that on drag and drop, **I'm never actually attaching the file to a form element**. I tried appending the file to $('#image').files, but apparently you can't do that for security issues . Basically I keep on reading that I can't add files programmatically.

Any guidance would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you have to attach `onload` event [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) you read the file.

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
      img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

**Example**

```js
var MAX_FILE_SIZE = Infinity; // ignore this

function eventImageSetup() {

  $(dropbox).height($('#imageBorder').height());

  fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function() {
    image.click();
  }, false);

  fileRemove.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!$('#preview').hasClass('hidden')) { // If there is an image uploaded
      $('#preview').empty();
      $('#dropbox').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#preview').addClass('hidden');
      $('#fileSelect').text('Upload Image');
      resetFileInputField();
    }
    removeError($('#imageError'), $('#image'));
  }, false);

  dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
  dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
  dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

} // end of eventImageSetup


function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  handleFiles(files);
}

function handleFiles(files) {


  var file = files[0];

  //console.log("This is the file: ", file);

  var imageType = /^image\//;
  if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
    // a bunch of code to deal with this...
    return;
  }
  if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
    // a bunch of code to deal with this..
    return;
  }
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    //adjustImageSize(img);
  };
  $('#dropbox').addClass('hidden');
  $('#preview').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#preview').empty();
  $('#preview').append(img);
  $('#fileSelect').text('Replace Image');
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

eventImageSetup();
```

```css
#dropbox {
  border: 2px dashed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="image" type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

<div id="imageBorder">
  <div id="imageContainer">

    <div id="dropbox">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p> Drop image here or click to upload</p>
    </div>

    <div id="preview" class="hidden">
    </div>

    <button id="fileSelect" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload Image</button>
    <button id="fileRemove" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Remove Image</button>

  </div>
```

**Side-remarks**

- Elements with ID attributes (which do not contain any dashes) can be referenced in the JavaScript using their ID value. For example, `<input id="fileSelect">` can be accessed using `fileSelect` instead of `document.getElementById('fileSelect')`.
- Button elements with `type="button"` will not submit the form upon click.

Comment: That is how I originally had it, but it didn't work unfortunately :(